# Local Storage some time return undefined in react-native

Tags: react-native

**Issue Description::**

I'm working on react-native application. I am getting user information from local storage, but some time it's return undefined. This working fine on debug mode, only problem in release mode.

**Code::**

```
let currentUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("CURRENT_USER");
let user = JSON.parse(currentUser);
```

**Version::**

```
"react": "^16.8.4",
"react-native": "^0.58.6"
```

Comment: In release mode you are getting `promise` I guess. Try to check the response before making it `JSON.parse`.

Comment: getItem will return a promise whether in debug or release mode

Comment: If you're loading user data inside your loading screen, make sure you don't navigate from the loading screen before it's **done** loading user data ...

Answer (score 1):

Your code should return a stored string if you have `setItem` earlier or null if you didn't. I don't know why the need for `JSON.parse`.
How about this:

```
async getUser() {
    let user = null;
    AsyncStorage.getItem("CURRENT_USER")
    .then((result) => {
        if (result !== null) {
            user = result;
        }
    });
    return user;
}
```